# Too many arguments to function 'rand'?

Tags: c

I have only used the function twice and it displays the aforementioned error. Can someone explain as to why the compiler does that?

```
void printrandom()
{
    int x = (rand(5)+1);
    int y = (rand(5)+1);
    printf("%d and %d - a total of %d", x, y, (x+y));
}
```

Comment: `rand` does not take arguments.

Comment: you can also try creating a function that will help you get a range

int rand_num(int from, int to)
{
    if (from == to) return to;

  else
  {
      int randNumber = from + (random() % (to - from));
  }
}

Answer (score 2):

It is actually `rand(void)`, which is why you are getting that error.

Try `int x = (rand() % 5) + 1;`

**EDIT** as Daniel points out, using `%` will actually affect the probability.  See [his link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984974/why-do-people-say-there-is-modulo-bias-when-using-a-random-number-generator) for how to address this issue.

Comment: -1. Using `rand() % N` is flawed and should be avoided. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984974/why-do-people-say-there-is-modulo-bias-when-using-a-random-number-generator) to find out why.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar: If the bias introduced by `rand() % 5` is a significant problem, then you should probably be using something better than `rand` anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Declaration for `rand()` function is

```
int rand(void);
```

This means that it takes no arguments. Remove `5` from `rand`. If you want to generate random numbers from `1` to `5`, the you can do this as

```
int x = rand()%5 + 1;
```

Comment: Indeed, that is another option.  But it will perform on average 400 million iterations to generate an in-range number...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth; True. But what is wrong with the answer. I mentioned both approaches.

Comment: Because what you've presented is a really bad solution ;)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth; Then you can go with first one. It is up to you ;)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I agree (and he's edited his answer), but the expected number of iterations depends on the value of `RAND_MAX`, which can be as small as `32767`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: That is true.